# (NOT) Netty calls to System.gc()

Tags: java, garbage-collection, netty

When reviewing GC logs for an application which is built upon, Netty, I noticed that there were GC events tagged with 'System.gc()' e.g.:

```
[GC (System.gc()) [PSYoungGen: 63506K->64K(637952K)] 126048K->62605K(2036224K), 0.0035823 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
[Full GC (System.gc()) [PSYoungGen: 64K->0K(637952K)] [ParOldGen: 62541K->62541K(1398272K)] 62605K->62541K(2036224K), [Metaspace: 82261K->82261K(1120256K)], 0.1926316 secs] [Times: user=0.47 sys=0.00, real=0.19 secs]
```

Upon a search of the code and the libraries in use, we have determined that these calls are coming from Netty (version 4.1.21 final).

I have not been able to find anything in the documentation or by searching that refers to this.  Is there anywhere I can read about why this is being done and what impact disabling explicit GC might have?  All I have been able to find is [this presentation](http://www.datascienceassn.org/sites/default/files/Netty%20-%20Asynchronous%20Network%20Application%20Framework.pdf) which notes something about System.gc() but has no useful information about it.

In the events I saw, it seemed that the GC was done at a sub-optimal time and that it executed a full-GC when none was needed and appears to have moved objects to the old generation unnecessarily.

**CORRECTION**: This was initially attributed to Netty but on further inspection it was found not to be the case.  Netty does not make calls to System.gc().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no System.gc() call triggered by netty itself. Just search the code-base there is nothing like this. That said the JVM may try to call `System.gc()` when you try to allocate a direct buffer and there is not enough memory left.

If this is the source of the `System.gc()` I would suggest to higher the max amount of direct memory the JVM is allowed to us.

Comment: Increasing the maximum direct memory, reducing the average buffer size, or not creating so many new connections would all help this. +1

Comment: I've added an example of the lines that are being written to the log.   The GC was forced when only 62MB of a 2GB heap was used.  There was basically no load on the app at the time this occurred.  It's very strange.

Comment: I presume you are the same Normal Maurer that wrote the presentation I linked to.  Can you explain what you meant on slide 33: "there is also Thread.sleep(100) and System.gc() ?!?"

Comment: The reference to System.gc seems to be to the Bits.reserveMemory() method in rt.jar.  I'm guessing your reference to sleep(100) and System.gc() was about that method and why it's bad and i take it it is not used in Netty 4.  Correct?  Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: My apologies, this is happening across a bunch of other apps that are not using Netty.  Definitely not Netty.